# How to use while loops with multiple if/elif statements?

Tags: python, while-loop

Trying to use a while statement to return to an opening prompt. 
I apologize for my garbage code.

I've tried assigning a True/False value to the while loop but the program just terminates when any input is given.

```
choice = eval(input('What would you like to convert? \n Farenheit to Celcius (1) \n Feet to Meters (2) \n Pounds to Kilograms (3) \n Ounces to Liters (4) \n : '))

 while choice:

    if choice == 1:

        degreesF = eval(input('Enter the temperature in degrees F: '))
        degreesC = 5/9*(degreesF - 32)
        print(degreesC, 'degrees Celcius')

    elif choice == 2: 

        distanceFeet = eval(input('Enter the distance in feet: '))
        distanceMeters = distanceFeet/3.28
        print(distanceMeters, 'm')

    elif choice == 3:

        Pounds = eval(input('Pounds: '))
        Kilograms = Pounds*0.45359237038
        print(Kilograms, 'kg')

    elif choice == 4:

        Ounces = eval(input('Ounces: '))
        Liters = Ounces*0.0295735
        print(Liters, 'L')
```

Currently, the program returns me to whatever I set the input as. For example, if I input 1, I can convert temperature but I am only able to convert temperature.

Comment: I recommend you do not use `eval`, but compare strings instead. It is safer.

Comment: Ah ok! What do you mean by safer? As in less chance of things going wrong?

Comment: Imagine my input was `__import__('os').system('something bad')` instead of an integer

Answer (score 3):

Putting below line inside a `while True` may result in what you expected:

```
choice = eval(input('What would you like to convert? \n Farenheit to Celcius (1) \n Feet to Meters (2) \n Pounds to Kilograms (3) \n Ounces to Liters (4) \n : '))
```

If I am not wrong, you need something like below:

```
while True:
    choice = eval(input('What would you like to convert? \n Farenheit to Celcius (1) \n Feet to Meters (2) \n Pounds to Kilograms (3) \n Ounces to Liters (4) \n : '))

    if choice == 1:

        degreesF = eval(input('Enter the temperature in degrees F: '))
        degreesC = 5/9*(degreesF - 32)
        print(degreesC, 'degrees Celcius')

    elif choice == 2: 

        distanceFeet = eval(input('Enter the distance in feet: '))
        distanceMeters = distanceFeet/3.28
        print(distanceMeters, 'm')

    elif choice == 3:

        Pounds = eval(input('Pounds: '))
        Kilograms = Pounds*0.45359237038
        print(Kilograms, 'kg')

    elif choice == 4:

        Ounces = eval(input('Ounces: '))
        Liters = Ounces*0.0295735
        print(Liters, 'L')
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I would give you an upvote your answer, but according to this website I am not reputable yet haha

Answer (score 3):

You like to include the input in the while-loop:

```
while True:
    choice = int(input('What would you like to convert? \n Farenheit to Celcius (1) \n Feet to Meters (2) \n Pounds to Kilograms (3) \n Ounces to Liters (4) \n : '))

    if choice == 1:
        degreesF = float(input('Enter the temperature in degrees F: '))
        degreesC = 5/9*(degreesF - 32)
        print(degreesC, 'degrees Celcius')
    elif choice == 2: 
        distanceFeet = float(input('Enter the distance in feet: '))
        distanceMeters = distanceFeet/3.28
        print(distanceMeters, 'm')
    elif choice == 3:
        Pounds = float(input('Pounds: '))
        Kilograms = Pounds*0.45359237038
        print(Kilograms, 'kg')
    elif choice == 4:
        Ounces = float(input('Ounces: '))
        Liters = Ounces*0.0295735
        print(Liters, 'L')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the purpose of the "break" ? I am unfamiliar with the function.

Comment: the only change I'd make here is to avoid casting "choice" as an int, and simply compare what's input with a string. i.e. `if choice == "1"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the eval line inside your while loop for it to run multiple times.

untested (pseudo) code:

```
while true:
your input line
your other code
```

this will run forever so I suggest doing somethig like this

```
while true:
  your input line
  if input == 0:
    break
  your other code
```

this will stop the while loop when you type 0

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of things, and for now you should make them explicit:

1. Your program should run forever, or until it is told to quit.
2. Your prompt for a menu selection should loop until it gets a valid answer.
3. Your inputs for numeric values should loop until they get valid answers.

**General Form of the Solution**

How can you do these things? In general, by starting with bad initial data, and looping until you see good data:

```
some_value = bad_data()
while some_value is bad:
    some_value = input("Enter some value: ")
```

A good "default" value for `bad_data()` is the special value `None`. You can write:

```
some_value = None
```

On the other hand, your `is bad` test might want a different kind of bad data, such as a string. You might consider using `''` as your bad data value:

```
some_value = ''
```

Finally, if your `is bad` test wants an integer value, maybe consider using a number you know is bad, or a number out of range (like a negative value):

```
some_value = 100
# or 
some_value = -1
```

For your specific problems:

**1. How do I run forever?**

You can run forever using a `while` loop that never exits. A while loop will run as long as the *condition* is true. Is there a value that is always true in Python? Yes! Its name is `True`:

```
while True:
    # runs forever
```

**2. How do I loop until my menu selection is valid?**

Using the general form, above, for an integer selection. Your menu asks the user to enter a number. You can check for a valid value either using *str*`.isdigit()` or using `try:/except:`. In python, the exception is the better choice:

```
choice = -1                           # Known bad value
while choice not in {1, 2, 3, 4}:     # {a,b,c} is a set
    instr = input('Choose 1..4')
    try:
        choice = int(instr)
    except:
        choice = -1
```

**3. How can I loop until I get a valid numeric value?**

For floating point numbers, like temperatures, you don't want to try to spell out an explicit set of allowed answers, or a range of numbers. Instead, use `None` (you could use `Nan`, but it's more characters for the same result).

```
temp = None
while temp is None:
    instr = input('Enter a temp: ')

    try:
        temp = float(instr)
    except:
        temp = None
```

Be aware that 'nan' is a valid float. So you might want to check for that and disallow it.

**How do I combine all these things?**

You put them together in blocks:

```
while True:   # run forever

    # Menu choice:
    choice = -1                           # Known bad value
    while choice not in {1, 2, 3, 4}:     # {a,b,c} is a set
        instr = input('Choose 1..4')
        try:
            choice = int(instr)
        except:
            choice = -1

    if choice == 1:
        # Now read temps
        temp = None
        while temp is None:
            instr = input('Enter a temp: ')

            try:
                temp = float(instr)
            except:
                temp = None
```